# Не удается подгрузить расширение SOS в WinDbg

Tags: .net, отладка, windbg

После загрузки управляемой программы в WinDbg (**File -> Open Executable...**) при попытке загрузить расширения из `sos.dll` возникает следующая ошибка:

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
Unable to find module 'clr'
```

Команды из SOS (`!bpmd`, `!dumpdomain` и т.д.) не работают. Как можно исправить данную ошибку и получить доступ к командам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что WinDbg останавливает выполнение программы на раннем этапе инициализации процесса, в функции `LdrpDoDebuggerBreak` модуля `ntdll`. В этот момент в ее адресное пространство еще не загружен рантайм `clr.dll`, поэтому и не удается подключить расширение SOS.

Необходимо поставить брейкпоинт на момент загрузки модуля `clr`, а еще лучше - на момент загрузки JIT-компилятора `clrjit`, т.к. в первом случае (как я предполагаю) еще не прочитаны метаданные программы, и часть SOS-команд, например, `!bpmd`, работать не будет.

Момент загрузки модуля отлавливается командой `sxe ld`:

```
0:000> sxe ld clrjit
0:000> g
```

После этого расширение подключается без ошибок:

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
0:000> !bpmd test.exe Test.Main
Found 1 methods in module 00007ff8efe740c0...
MethodDesc = 00007ff8efe75980
Adding pending breakpoints...
```